# Debugging Swift / Objective-C

Tags: swift, lldb

I have a Parse subclass called PaymentInfo defined as

```swift
class PaymentInfo: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

override class func initialize() {
    var once: dispatch_once_t = 0;
    dispatch_once(&once) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}

static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "PaymentInfo"
}

@NSManaged var paymentUserID: String!
@NSManaged var walletID: String!

convenience init(userID: String, walletID: String) {
    self.init()
    self.paymentUserID = userID
    self.walletID = walletID
}

}
```

While debugging in lldb, I get hold of an instance and look at the member

```
(lldb) expr self.paymentInfo
(Nestor.PaymentInfo!) $R0 = 0x00007f9e15805740 {
  Parse.PFObject = {...}
}
(lldb) po $R0
<PaymentInfo: 0x7f9e15805740, objectId: 2gKS5LhD35, localId: (null)> {
    paymentUserID = 10104705;
    walletID = 10104706;
}
```

So far so good. But where I don't get it is the following:

```
(lldb) expr $R0.paymentUserID
2015-12-17 16:09:17.432 Nestor[3474:482967] -[PFObject paymentUserID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9e15805740
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Apparently, lldb knows that $R0 is an IUO of (qualified) type Nestor.PaymentInfo! but when asking for the paymentUserID property that information is lost... Why ?

Or do I miss something ?

Thanks

B

Answer (score 0):

This must be fixed in Xcode 7.2 because it works for me using your class.

Comment: Weird cause I also use Xcode 7.2. How can you check the version of the dev tools Xcode is actually using ? Maybe for some reason it uses an older version...

Comment: I was also running the iPad Air 2 Simulator. In Xcode Preferences you can check Locations. I have Xcode 7.2 (7C68)